# Removing the Crown / Neck paper

Tags: style, serving

I recently moved to Germany and took Rothaus Pils here at the party. I opened the cap after tearing the crown/neck paper (Gold colored paper as shown below) partially.

Reference Image :[image]

I was told that Germans really don't like to keep that crown/neck paper. I wanted to ask for reason, but felt it is too rude. Is there any specific reason behind removing the crown paper

Comment: Enjoy your stay there.  I've only spent time in Bavaria, but they were very friendly and wouldn't mind answering any question about customs, etc.  Beer was always poured into the proper glass for the style of beer.  I can't remember anyone drinking from the bottle.

Comment: Dunno where are you from but in Europe generally there's nothing rude in asking for reasons, including the reason why paper should be removed. Next time go ahead and ask.

Answer (score 9):

I'm from Germany. Don't care too much about this. Just remove that part of it which would be disturbing when drinking, since some minor pieces might get into the glass or into your mouth directly if you are drinking out of the bottle, which is common in Germany, except in a restaurant or during a dinner.

Also you wouldn't normally remove the gold paper *before* opening the bottle. Most of the parts will getting removed *automatically* when opening it. You just need to remove the remaining, disturbing parts, if there are any left. Try it! ;)

That's all you need to know. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

I can imagine multiple reasons. I assume that Rothaus owns the patents to this kind of glueless neckpaper fixing what leds to a feeling belonging to the 1337 group of zäpfle-fans as the common germann biertrinker is always prowd of his local beer. First, this kind of wrapping the top makes sence from an hyenic point of view. Second, since they wrap their aluminium foil, which is thick compared to others, not just around the neck but also over the cab, you may have realised that the artifacts caused from opening the bottle feels uncomfortable on the lips. But most important, biertrinkers are way conservative on anything related to their local beer. Prost!